# Suitable econometric specification for my data

Tags: econometrics, regression, fixed-effects

I'm playing around with my dataset and as a start, I want to understand whether the absenteeism and vaccination rates for employees across a large number of factories with separate units is dependent on the few vaccination drives that took place across these units.

My outcome of interests (at the employee level) are *absenteeism* which is a % for each individual employee, who are part of a specific unit within a factory for each week of the years 2020 and 2021. My second outcome of interest is *vaccination status* (which is a dummy variable for the vaccination status of an employee).

My two Independent variables (at the unit level) are:

i) **'Cumulative frequency of vaccine drives'** - this variables is the cumulative number of "vaccine camps" (a day in which > 1 person was vaccinated in the unit) a unit has had as of week t

and ii)  **'Cumulative frequency of people vaccinated'** - this variables is the cumulative number of people vaccinated in a unit by week t

For this, I have defined few basic models to understand this question.

The models I'm using are

1. FE regression model with the DV and IV(controlling for for unit and week fixed effects)
2. FE regression model with the DV and IV (controlling for for individual and week fixed effects)
3. FE regression model (controlling for for unit and week fixed effects) with the first lead IV variable (to capture any pre-trends)
4. FE regression model (controlling for for unit and week fixed effects) with the second lead IV variable (to capture any pre-trends)
5. FE regression model (controlling for for unit and week fixed effects) with the third lead IV variable (to capture any pre-trends)
6. FE regression model (controlling for for unit and week fixed effects) with ALL the lead IV variables

My question is, do these models/specifications make sense to understand my research questions and do you see any issues with the model or specifications? like for example, in model  #6, would the inclusion of all the leads together create a problem with multicollinearity?

Thank you and please feel free to ask any questions!

Edit: few more details to help. My model is a linear model with many fixed effects. There are around 203,690   observations at the employee level. The other endogenous variables and instruments i have are i)education, ii)gender, iii) skill level and iv) age

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing (i) the whole econometric model (linear or nonlinear?, etc) ; (ii) how many observations for a given individual you have (for the individual fixed effects) ; (iii) which variables are endogenous, and which and how many instruments you have (and how strong your instruments are...)

Comment: Thank you! It's a linear model with many fixed effects. There are around 203,690   observations at the employee level. The other endogenous variables and instruments i have are i)education, ii)gender, iii) skill level and iv) age